# How many clauses in this sentence?

Tags: clauses

> That’s less than what some analysts have signaled Goldman might have to pay.

Three clauses and a missing "that" ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it has three clauses.

The 'that' between 'signaled' and 'Goldman' is unnecessary. The sentence is grammatically correct with or without it, but we would usually leave it out.

'They said I could leave' is more idiomatic than 'They said that I could leave'.

In this sentence . . .

*They said Goldman might have to pay more, and that if he didn't penalties might be imposed.*

. . . the 'that' reminds us that this is still **they** who are speaking.